# AWS Lambda chaining functions won't print my logging

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying a super **simple test with AWS lambda for chaining functions** and any drawbacks to it.

*I want to make a more complex use of them (optimizing images as fast as possible for a gigantic bucket on S3)*

So I said to myself, let's try first to get the arguments from the first function into the second one and so on, before I went crazy.

> Also I've seen people recommend to use Step Functions so just trying
>   to avoid that unless it's really necessary.

*So as the title says*, **I can't get the second function, the one being invoked to print out stuff**, I'd love it for debugging purposes and wondering if there's a way to make it work?

Here's my code:

```
    'use strict';
    var aws = require('aws-sdk')

    module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
      var lambda = new aws.Lambda()
      var testPayload = ['blue', 'green', 'red']
      var opts = {
        FunctionName: 'lambda-chaining-dev-ciao',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(testPayload)
      }

      lambda.invoke(opts, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error : ', err)
          callback(err, null)
        } else if (data) {
          console.log('data', data)
          console.log('\n')
          const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.parse(data.Payload)
          }
          callback(null, response)
        }
      })
    }

    module.exports.ciao = (event, context, callback) => {
      console.log("I will never be logged when invoked")
      callback(null,{ message: 'this is a test'})
    }
```

serverless.yml

```
    service: lambda-chaining
    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs6.10
      iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
            - lambda:InvokeAsync
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
          Resource: "*"
    functions:
      hello:
        handler: handler.hello
      ciao:
        handler: handler.ciao
    plugins:
      - serverless-offline
```

Comment: Does your second Lambda function have a role attached? That role needs `log:*` permissions, such as provided by the default `AWSLambdaExecute` policy.

Comment: The second function is running in an entirely different container, and will be writing to an entirely different CloudWatch log group.  It isn't going to write anything to the logs of the function that invokes it.

Comment: I added the log permissions to my serverless.yml file. I am running the invocation locally to see the console.log works on the second function and still nothing. (Attaching my yml file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `LogType: 'Tail'` to your Lambda params if you want to see logs from the invoke. It's not a great solution for what you want, as it's only going to be the last 4kb of logs.

If you're trying to see logs from the actual process of Lambda 2 and not in the Lambda 1 process and they're not there, I would question whether Lambda 1 is even executing. You could try `fs.writeFileSync()` to verify. Or, if you're not running it locally, just look at Cloudwatch invocation metrics for the function.

Also, you will have Lambda 1 running the entire time Lambda 2 is running. If Lambda 2 calls another Lambda, Lambda 1 will have to wait for that, ad infinitum. Eventually you'll start timing the functions out or paying Amazon a lot more money.

This is a situation for Step Functions, if you want to retain your sanity.